# Django "Enter a list of values" form error when rendering a ManyToManyField as a Textarea

Tags: django

I'm trying to learn Django and I've ran into some confusing points. I'm currently having trouble creating a movie using a form. The idea of the form is to give the user any field he'd like to fill out. Any field that the user fills out will be updated in its respective sql table (empty fields will be ignored). But, the form keeps giving me the error "Enter a list of values" when I submit the form. To address this, I thought stuffing the data from the form into a list and then returning that list would solve this.

The first idea was to override the `clean()` in my ModelForm. However, because the form fails the `is_valid()` check in my views, the `cleaned_data` variable in `clean()` doesn't contain anything. Next, I tried to override the `to_python()`. However, `to_python()` doesn't seem to be called.

If I put `__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase` in the respective model, I receive the runtime error

> "TypeError: Error when calling the
>   metaclass bases
>       metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a
>   (non-strict) subclass of the
>   metaclasses of all its bases"

My approach doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure how to get around the 'Enter a list of values" error! Any advice?

Here is the relevant code (updated):

```
models.py

""" Idea:
A movie consists of many equipments, actors, and lighting techniques. It also has a rank for the particular movie, as well as a title. 

A Theater consists of many movies.

A nation consists of many theaters. 
"""

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EquipmentModel(models.Model):
        equip = models.CharField(max_length=20)
#       user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class ActorModel(models.Model):
        actor = models.CharField(max_length=20)
#       user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class LightModel(models.Model):
        light = models.CharField(max_length=20)
#       user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class MovieModel(models.Model):
#       __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase   
        rank = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5000, decimal_places=3)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

        equipments = models.ManyToManyField(EquipmentModel, blank=True, null=True)
        actors = models.ManyToManyField(ActorModel, blank=True, null=True)
        lights = models.ManyToManyField(LightModel, blank=True, null=True)

class TheaterModel(models.Model):
        movies = models.ForeignKey(MovieModel)

class NationModel(models.Model):
        theaters = models.ForeignKey(TheaterModel)

=====================================
forms.py

""" 
These Modelforms tie in the models from models.py

Users will be able to write to any of the fields in MovieModel when creating a movie.
Users may leave any field blank (empty fields should be ignored, ie: no updates to database).
"""

from django import forms
from models import MovieModel
from django.forms.widgets import Textarea

class MovieModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
             super(MovieModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
             self.fields["actors"].widget = Textarea()
             self.fields["equipments"].widget = Textarea()
             self.fields["lights"].widget = Textarea()

       def clean_actors(self):
             data = self.cleaned_data.get('actors')
             print 'cleaning actors'
             return [data]


      class Meta:
            model = MovieModel

=============================================
views.py

""" This will display the form used to create a MovieModel """

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from forms import MovieModelForm

def add_movie(request):
       if request.method == "POST":
             form = MovieModelForm(request.POST)

             if form.is_valid():
                    new_moviemodel = form.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/data/')

       else:
             form = MovieModelForm()

       return render_to_response('add_movie_form.html', {form:form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Please reformat this so that it's comprehendible.

Comment: Sorry, first time using stackoverflow. Trying to get the <code> tags working

Comment: Just use the indenting approach.

Comment: Push the button with the brackets `{}` , and use '`' to format inline code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The probable problem is that the list of values provided in the text area can not be normalized into a list of Models.

See the [ModelMultipleChoiceField documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield).

The field is expecting a list of valid IDs, but is probably receiving a list of text values, which django has no way of converting to the actual model instances. The `to_python` will be failing within the form field, not within the form itself. Therefore, the values never even reach the form.

Is there something wrong with using the built in ModelMultipleChoiceField? It will provide the easiest approach, but will require your users to scan a list of available actors (I'm using the actors field as the example here).

Before I show an example of how I'd attempt to do what you want, I must ask; how do you want to handle actors that have been entered that don't yet exist in your database? You can either create them if they exist, or you can fail. You need to make a decision on this.

```
# only showing the actor example, you can use something like this for other fields too

class MovieModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    actors_list = fields.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea())

    class Meta:
        model = MovieModel
        exclude = ('actors',)

    def clean_actors_list(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        actors_list = data.get('actors_list', None)
        if actors_list is not None:
            for actor_name in actors_list.split(','):
                try:
                    actor = Actor.objects.get(actor=actor_name)
                except Actor.DoesNotExist:
                    if FAIL_ON_NOT_EXIST: # decide if you want this behaviour or to create it
                        raise forms.ValidationError('Actor %s does not exist' % actor_name)
                    else: # create it if it doesnt exist
                        Actor(actor=actor_name).save()
        return actors_list

    def save(self, commit=True):
        mminstance = super(MovieModelForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        actors_list = self.cleaned_data.get('actors_list', None)
        if actors_list is not None:
            for actor_name in actors_list.split(","):
                actor = Actor.objects.get(actor=actor_name)
                mminstance.actors.add(actor)

        mminstance.save()
        return mminstance
```

The above is all untested code, but something approaching this should work if you really want to use a Textarea for a ModelMultipleChoiceField. If you do go down this route, and you discover errors in my code above, please either edit my answer, or provide a comment so I can. Good luck.

Edit:

The other option is to create a field that understands a comma separated list of values, but behaves in a similar way to ModelMultipleChoiceField. Looking at the source code for ModelMultipleChoiceField, it inhertis from ModelChoiceField, which DOES allow you to define which value on the model is used to normalize.

```
## removed code because it's no longer relevant. See Last Edit ##
```

**Edit:**

Wow, I really should have checked the django trac to see if this was already fixed. It is. See the [following ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9161) for information. Essentially, they've done the same thing I have. They've made ModelMutipleChoiceField respect the `to_field_name` argument. **This is only applicable for django 1.3!**

The problem is, the regular ModelMultipleChoiceField will see the comma separated string, and fail because it isn't a List or Tuple. So, our job becomes a little more difficult, because we have to change the string to a list or tuple, before the regular clean method can run.

```
class ModelCommaSeparatedChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    widget = Textarea
    def clean(self, value):
        if value is not None:
            value = [item.strip() for item in value.split(",")] # remove padding
        return super(ModelCommaSeparatedChoiceField, self).clean(value)
```

So, now your form should look like this:

```
class MovieModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    actors = ModelCommaSeparatedChoiceField(
               required=False, 
               queryset=Actor.objects.filter(), 
               to_field_name='actor')
    equipments = ModelCommaSeparatedChoiceField(
               required=False,
               queryset=Equipment.objects.filter(),
               to_field_name='equip')
    lights = ModelCommaSeparatedChoiceField(
               required=False, 
               queryset=Light.objects.filter(),
               to_field_name='light')

    class Meta:
        model = MovieModel
```

Comment: I'll try this and let you know! Thanks!

Comment: @sharkfin, see my final update. If you're using django 1.3 (you should be for a new project!), the last edit should be the cleanest way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks, Josh. I'm able to see clean() being called and the value being passed in, but now it tells me `clean() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: This will fix the error: `return super(ModelCommaSeparatedChoiceField, self).clean(value)`

Comment: @shark whoops yeah thanks for the edit. So did this method work for you?

Comment: With your updated code, I'm trying to use `clean_actors()` to add the actor text if it's not already in the actor database table. `clean_actors()` (inside `MovieModelForm`) never seems to be called though?

Comment: Nope, that's not going to work. Inside the ModelMultipleChoiceField, it validates that the values already exist, and throws an error if they don't. This is done in the field clean() method, not the form clean method. It will never make it through to the form. Look into the source code of django.forms.models.ModelMultipleChoiceField, that will give you a much clearer picture. I don't think it's a good idea to allow users to enter so many instances in that way.. you really would be better off keeping a separate form for adding actors/lights/equipment independently. My 2 cents.

Comment: Twelve years later, still the best answer on the web.  Thank you!  My solution only required that custom field and form.

Answer (score 0):

`to_python` AFAIK is a method for fields, not forms.

`clean()` occurs after individual field cleaning, so your `ModelMultipleChoiceFields` `clean()` methods are raising validation errors and thus `cleaned_data` does not contain anything.

You haven't provided examples for what kind of data is being input, but the answer lies in form field cleaning.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

You need to write validation specific to that field that either returns the correct data in the  format your field is expecting, or raises a `ValidationError` so your view can re-render the form with error messages.

**update**: You're probably missing the `ModelForm` `__init__` -- see if that fixes it.

```
class MovieModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
             super(MovieModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
             self.fields["actors"].widget = Textarea()

      def clean_actors(self):
          data = self.cleaned_data.get('actors')
          # validate incoming data. Convert the raw incoming string 
          # to a list of ids this field is expecting.
          # if invalid, raise forms.ValidationError("Error MSG")
          return data.split(',') # just an example if data was '1,3,4'
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. The `clean_actors(self)` doesn't seem to be called either though. The input can be anything.

Comment: With a second look at the code, it looks like you are not calling the superclass `__init__` - that should trigger an `AttributeError` saying either `fields` doesn't exist or `actors` doesn't exist. Very odd. : )

Comment: Oh oops, I must have deleted that when I was editing my post. Otherwise you're right: 'self.fields' would have thrown some error.

But the clean problem still persists. It's not being called. I printed out the form, and it looked something like this:

`[(u'actors', u'testing actors'), ..... ]`

Comment: It's not being called at all? That's odd. I just tested on a fresh `ModelForm`, and `clean_FIELD` does get called. Not sure what to say...

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to redo this and see what happens. I'll let you know (I have to get ready for something now, blarg). Thank you for the suggestions so far!

Comment: Josh's post seems to work, but `clean_actors()` still isn't being called for the ModelForm. I want to add the text to the database if it's not already in it. Any reason why this is?

Comment: Why clean_actors isn't being called - I have no idea. I can not reproduce this on django 1.3. I created a fresh ModelForm for a model with an m2m field, defined nothing but a clean_method and an `__init__` widget override as you have done, and the clean methods are called.