# Trying to save ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django “Enter a list of values” form error when rendering a ManyToManyField as a Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608576/django-enter-a-list-of-values-form-error-when-rendering-a-manytomanyfield-as-a)

I have `python,django,ajax` these data in `artist` input field. I am getting `Enter a list of values.`error. Will you please help me to save these data? thanks

## Model

```
artist = models.ManyToManyField(ApiArtist, blank=True)
```

## Form and Validation

```
class ApiSongForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ApiSong
        widgets = {
            'artist': forms.TextInput(),
        }

    def clean_artist(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        artist_list = data.get('artist', None)
        if artist_list is not None:
            for artist_name in artist_list.split(','):
                artist = ApiArtist(name=artist_name).save()
        return artist_list
```

## EDIT

Now I've changed the code copy/paste from provided link. But and I am getting `Cannot resolve keyword 'artist' into field. Choices are: apisong, id, name`. error message.
Here is my [ApiArtist and SongModel](http://dpaste.org/s35RH/). thanks

```
class ModelCommaSeparatedChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    widget = forms.TextInput
    def clean(self, value):
        if value is not None:
            print value
            value = [item.strip() for item in value.split(",")]  # remove padding
        return super(ModelCommaSeparatedChoiceField, self).clean(value)

class ApiSongForm(ModelForm):
    artist = ModelCommaSeparatedChoiceField(
               required=False, queryset=ApiArtist.objects.filter(), to_field_name='artist')
    class Meta:
        model = ApiSong
```

Comment: Please include the traceback for your error.

Comment: @jdi I am just getting `Enter a list of values`. I am not getting any traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now my following code is working. Thanks anyways

```
class ApiSongForm(ModelForm):
    artist = forms.CharField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(ApiSongForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        artists = self.cleaned_data.get('artist', None)
        if artists is not None:
            for artist_name in artists.split(","):
                artist = ApiArtist.objects.create(name=artist_name)
                instance.artist.add(artist)

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't be saving things in the clean method.

Secondly, your code doesn't convert the value from the textinput to a list. You have a `split` in your if statement, but you don't set the result back to `artist_list` before returning it.

Comment: I also tried `return artist_list.split(',')`. But Same.